# jquery file upload plugin submits whole form

Tags: jquery, forms, file-upload, validation

I'm using jquery [file upload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) with `<input type="file">` tag in form. Form also has other fields but they are not for submitting to server. 
Is it possible to upload only file and not the whole form? I am using jquery [validator plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) so after uploading a file, form submit is triggered and all empty field are marked as not valid. 
I could move away `<input type="file">` from form but I need it inline between other form elements. Form is dynamic so I don't want to position it absolutely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-form-data) you can find info about `formData` option:

> If you set the `formData` option, these fields won't be sent to the server...

So you can set it to empty array and rest form fields will not be sent, only files:

```
$('#foo').fileupload({
    ...,
    formData: [],
    ...,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with HTML5 New Form Attribute called 'novalidate' Attribute. It specifies that the form-data (input) should not be validated when submitted.

Example:

```
<form action="demo.php" novalidate>
E-mail: <input type="email" name="user_email">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Here in the above html code the input field is not validated and the data is submitted successfully.

Comment: I need validation for my other form fields and I do validation on form submit event. I want to submit form when user clicks SUBMIT button but not on file upload.